# Vue: Получить метод из компонента, который находится в скопед-слоте

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Component Page:**

```
...
<Child>
  <template #form="{ init }">
    <PageForm :init="init"/>
...
```

**Component PageForm:**

```
...
methods: {
  getData() {
    // меня должен вызвать компонент-внук Page-компонента
  }
}
...
```

**Component Child (render-function):**

```
...
h('GrandChild', {scopedSlots: {form = props => h('div', this.$scopedSlots.form(props)}}
...
```

**Component GrandChild:**

template:

```
...
<div>
  <slot name="form" :init="init">
<div>
...
```

script:

```
...
mounted: {
  // как здесь получить метод getData из Page-> PageForm без Vuex?
}
...
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что Вы хотите слишком многого от Vue... Да и зачем, если у Вас и так есть `mounted` в дочернем компоненте, в котором Вы можете вызвать то что нужно?

Comment: Я подозревала такой ответ) Я понимаю, что это неявный вызов, и быть может вовсе реализуемый (или равный ему костыльный) вариант. Но задачу поставили, а я не могу в меру своих коммуникационных компетенций доказать, что это больше похоже на костыль и уж лучше прокидывать пропсы, которые будут тоглить нужные события.

Comment: Если структура компонентов постоянна, то можно попробовать this.$parent.$parent.getData();

Comment: По идее можно `ref` повесить на компонент, и через него получить метод, но поведение там непредсказуемое... Вообще да, правильнее всего через props/emit обмениваться данными, если компоненты соседние.

Comment: @ВикторКарев да, тоже была идея, но так можно дойти до Page, а внутрь PageForm проблематично, т.к. это область слота

Comment: @VladimirGonchar согласна. Буду отталкиваться от того, что не я одна так думаю)